# How do i turn an input from a text box into a variable in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have an input whose value I want to store in a React variable.

```
<div>
  <label>Nombre Completo: </label>
  <input style={eachBit} required id='name' type='text' placeholder='Zeus Aurel'></input>
</div>
```

Without the complications of constructor or classes, I can't find anything useful anywhere. I know nothing of reactjs, please help.

Comment: Do you have some code that you're working on? Otherwise I'd have to say learn react before trying to do something in react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing data in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48356854/storing-data-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

onChange event allows value to be stored in state. Here is how input value is stored in a state named inputValue.

```
<input 
  onChange={e => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })) 
/>
```

Comment: but how can i use it when declaring the variable itself??

Comment: You could use this.state.inputValue anywhere. If you don’t like to save in state, store it in this.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the "e" supposed to mean in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the way to change/insert a HTML element as a variable ?

Hope this topic can help you : [Insert HTML with React Variable Statements (JSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx)

Comment: this is the opposite of what i'm looking for :/